# too surprised to say something vs too surprised to say anything

Tags: pronouns

Could you explain which sentence is more correct?

As I know in positive sentences we use "something" rather than "anything". But in the key to exercises I saw the second sentence.
I was surprised about it.

> I was too surprised to say something.
>
> I was too surprised to say anything.

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"anything" is correct here.

"Something" would refer to a specific thing which was intended to be said.

If that is what you mean, you would say:

"I was going to say something, but I was too surprised"

or:

"I was too surprised to say something that needed saying"

or whatever it is that would have qualified that "something".

But in this context, "anything" covers all and every one of the possible "somethings" which may have been in your mind to say at that time -- and because of your surprise, you could not say any of them.

The point is, this is actually a *negative* sentence. "I could *not* say anything, because my surprise prevented it."